# Cut variables from .htaccess rewriting

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this link: www.example.org/thumbnail.php?file=image.jpg&size=article_medium

and I redirect to : www.example.org/files/image.jpg

with this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^file=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^thumbnail.php$ /files/%1 [R=301,L]
```

but the link redirect to www.example.org/files/image.jpg&size=article_medium
and given the visitor 404 error , how to cut "&size=article_medium" in the rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are matching to the end of line.  Try

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^file=(.*)\&.*$ [NC]
```